permissions of the file system inside the docker is messed up, how to upgrade docker-compose version
Recently observed that file system inside docker container (without any changes) is messed up and this is impacting many as per: https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/issues/465
There are such other issues logged too.
The solution mentioned is: This is likely due to the update to Debian Bullseye -- you'll need to update Docker.
Now, we have multiple containers and need them to communicate on same network and some dependency. So we use docker-compose.
yaml file is as below sample:
version: '2'

services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:13-alpine3.19
        command: postgres -c 'max_connections=500'
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=user
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
            - POSTGRES_DB=mydb
        volumes:
            - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        networks:
            commonNet:

    pgbouncer:
        image: "bitnami/pgbouncer:1.16.0"
        restart: always
        environment:
            - POSTGRESQL_HOST=postgres
            - POSTGRESQL_USERNAME=user
            - POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=password
            - PGBOUNCER_DATABASE=mydb
        ports:
            - "1234:1234"
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        networks:
            commonNet:


    webserver:
        image: apache/airflow:2.3.0-python3.9
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - postgres
            - pgbouncer
        environment:
            - <ENV VARS>
        volumes:
            - <Mount volumes>    
        ports:
            - "5678:5678"
        entrypoint: /entrypoint.sh
        networks:
            commonNet:

    worker:
        image: apache/airflow:2.3.0-python3.9
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - webserver
        user: ${USER_ID}:0
        environment:
            - <ENV variables>
        volumes:
            - <volumes>
        command: celery worker
        networks:
            commonNet:

    
volumes:
    postgres-db-volume:
    workervolume:

networks:
    commonNet:
        ipam:
            config:
                - subnet: XX.XX.XX.XX/24

Now since we are using docker-compose to bring up our containers and everything, what should be the solution to upgrade docker-compose?
Just picking up latest docker-compose for linux will work, i.e. is it equivalent to upgrade docker version?
